# Update using push operator in MongoDB, getting syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and currently I am learning it. But at a point I got syntax error and I unable to find out that error. So, I need your help.

Code:

```
let reviewText1: [
    "The Martian could have been a sad drama file, instead it was a ",
    "hilarious file weith a little bit of dra,a added to it. The Martian is what ",
    "everybody wants from a space adventure. Ridley Scott can still make great ",
    "movies and this is one of his best."
].join() db.movieDetails.updateOne({
        title:"The Martian"
    }, {
        $push: {
            reviews: {
                rating: 4.5,
                date: ISODate("2016-01-12T09:00:00Z"),
                reviewer: "Spencer H.",
                text: reviewText1
            }
        }
    })
```

Error:

> 2020-02-03T08:29:30.381+0530 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: u
>   nexpected token: ':' :
>   @(shell):1:15

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use colon after variable name in JavaScript, there should be:

```js
let reviewText1 = [
    "The Martian could have been a sad drama file, instead it was a ",
    "hilarious file weith a little bit of dra,a added to it. The Martian is what ",
    "everybody wants from a space adventure. Ridley Scott can still make great ",
    "movies and this is one of his best."
].join()

console.log(reviewText1)
```